# observe a single element from the array

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-android

I'm encountering two issues with the code here,

1. How to create an observer that can observer on a single array item instead of whole array.
2. AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() is throwing an error

   ```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val greetings = arrayOf("Hello A", "Hello B", "Hello C")

    val observable = Observable.fromArray(greetings)

    val observer = object: DisposableObserver<Array<String>>() {
        override fun onNext(t: Array<String>?) {
            println(t)
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {

        }

        override fun onComplete() {

        }
    }

    observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(observer)
   ```

   }

Error from #2

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.fromarraydemo, PID: 11002
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers.<clinit>(AndroidSchedulers.java:33)
        at io.reactivex.rxjava3.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers.mainThread(AndroidSchedulers.java:44)
        at com.example.fromarraydemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:36)
```

---

Attempt for #1

```
val observer = object: DisposableObserver<String>() {
    override fun onNext(t: String?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onComplete() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

}
```

but then `.subscribeWith(observer)` has an issue

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is <no name provided>! but Observer<in Array<String>!>! was expected
```

Comment: you want to observe single value then why don't just create an observable with Observable.just(array[index]) ?

Comment: oh sorry, i mean i want to iterate through all values for the array and want on observe each one on the 'onNext'

Comment: I don't get you, why are you observing an immutable array?

Answer (score 0):

About error #1, I think there is a function

```
val observable = greetings.toObservable()
```

that appears to do what you are looking for (use with your attempt `DisposableObserver<String>`)

About error #2, I copy-pasted your code and didn't receive any errors on AndroidSchedulers.mainThread(), but I'm using rxjava2 so it was not the exact same scenario. (The only changes I did to work in here is remove the optional from String and Throwable)

Maybe if you don't find a better solution, go back to rxjava2 can be an option?

Answer (score 0):

```
Based on @AppDeveloper's comment,

"i mean i want to iterate through all values for the array and want on observe each one on the 'onNext'"
```

you can use
`fromIterable()` to eject each value in this array, and observe each on the onNext();
`fromArray()` is to eject the whole array.

```
Observable.fromIterable(arrays)
       .subscribeOn(SchedulerProvider.io())
       .observeOn(SchedulerProvider.mainThread())
       .subscribe(
           {TODO("do on Next")},
           {TODO("do on Error")}
        )
```